# How much of the node modules is included in my main JS bundle?

Tags: webpack, node-modules, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I ran Webpack Bundle Analyzer to check the size of all of my node modules, but how much is being contributed into my main React JS bundle compiled by Webpack?

i.e if my main React JS bundle weighs 1.2MB after magnification and gzip, and one of my packages' size is 500KB parsed and 350KB gzipped, does that mean it would be 350KB of my 1.2MB JS bundle since my bundle is gzipped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is awkward..

For some reason i was too blind to see that webpack-bundle-analyzer gives you the size of your node modules **and** the rest of your application.